# String lexical order compare function is not safe in Java?

Tags: java, string, sorting, string-comparison

I have this function `isAsc(String a String b)` in java to compare two string in lexical order

```
public static void quickSort(String[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    String pivot = arr[middle];

    int i = low;
    int j = high;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (isAsc(arr[i], pivot) == true)
            i++;

        while (isAsc(pivot, arr[j]) == true) 
            j--;

        if (i <= j) {
            String temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (low < j)
        quickSort(arr, low, j);
    if (high > i)
        quickSort(arr, i, high);
}

private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length()) {
        return true;
    } else if (a.length() == b.length()) {
        boolean yep = true;
        for (int i =0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
            if (a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                yep = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return yep;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
      String[] unsorted = new String[n];
      for(int unsorted_i=0; unsorted_i < n; unsorted_i++){
         unsorted[unsorted_i] = in.next();
    }

    quickSort(unsorted, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(unsorted[i]);
    }
}
```

Basically, I will compare same-length strings in lexical order, and I consider `a==b` and `a>b` case as `non-ascending`. It works for two strings. But when I invoke this function in another quick sort function as comparison function, it will fail to sort some String array for me. For example, if I pass in this case:

```
100
6046724675206781253805417697364063874537349942332939012160502967377173420319837265456476
72091970412420810
3746855980099062683149629582771
4763506513
4381858583387279277494367930538
195294541694873319042720380485249001380825565396311663127260228626400961443707964165554187168383846
57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460
3443449340302668605052308
799898013447209990576845913871859165418584121624031762316631
3300953792
8
63593696
24851084103
407248179926838952899179921191873979655396776466610725637337844938107386865231
347055068146981261045909920471491104435367358281493074132530787003286631891260
84617645710
79889616038675409793789137873748992624206633449485792697950955
89010681446075323502110552896366
56055923387811165695520181970960556995748385
982252143663373494231929681150950636211
689652207582048074063885557314598131439882640463089732166634627009727882839802329
103760370650030890704420196453564751405138564548779976442730
2568508222553899614989132
595511428927857027243741014585070698077724714702592038259539625900191041
2006589875623412145878326
5346081954679885708665439539884162946087234174562850518034347368864646546761391881199484426332
41417855736231689319726325108873908732322628
82
4513813970506423806366556964549587926118285563093984149180914445198582562248005532967426935363394
189464003228859631246844678939878442100631407094488634370181145
6766894084508701303181966954454442649
617218738782517673738696836650709347
138693350046179064920029198428
69689336023779290
3123578614526005010789440062175923385894745490067711730621296066747362
6920677972668613791679
98727463407922846430489331897187874972506399980149269216341792683934266326553372651336825100910502
887419023647277091177508895423672748680390346760451960405476096892458561446000021772
357047822507894621064882425810251495984339153706718863150434921883251916931938
721655363593196254631465218524410129464006729720524491959093939538800477879025
399461832935777584631551322242458863336488933972064475755775387970693429489605542902103453
4879666158760447227244804904490661525075569972625784785166402241961211585507098
424250809729923008382471798976997991102352666012166168135388490453419791993437348248692902
96648
3499362168023660581620889357853145012397063659728
44
75655297913491802872733439380949625942090642103288135379733240968108838187718699296561107131
6730285737803282364443175816103191082917262371727029128242169800609774
2226233916493298335782492406184
702616993760099773277701
6459413133895599543512093010172681584992295387756374602296715030084689407214761953434
88151
48048060500795311454501362396164002281
13350830253644406272592098943542479448539695237424116030768219886
8602096560157018758
4285137293297191396703
59064571843258418539809783946176028799168327197
7352625455571982316988892359385804345281600126036030867648944342681034
841914798700287274894330827423742367016300562418119497681768534733683171159
966
871937317295006166948610659392371453127620
97717671655657189481516207050719062493363178584
44466191365953341779604153931359991009249825932467038
4900146572543628830293235422623540449026979
663851293951736587506669665707856376236045468061542850096311090080985050730443008535949871380862
3266084681485344181145502865406724087976265728762903576706273055985600897547821990716776855603
3027671510958920867119822769967026975150513671872284364883316076664947814983178816236371615
6075082871705572350813503266092842439231032244
226308783007518652278892711651945969504116481446022861103004230456764884348840645054713740
4827062832427344897934914852861881127816196306013748993413309020967615943118038713
82226197486758707862569829863301345843404256425288167712035595632448134024
6853035336068603185837379598609710965901821183057340152937719965
96144167763113033526215836335259504732455722379148990370590444393
497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314
8029462867402623010267220669038328276828159277704969882249658925340931197482
29961611875126871444847810377719588732057005401
7140136715304755447794330632416535814668937888353462780963074
86212388
139324591
2531882366050391355575974134566968043538613212060996149075948904530719392416580359757169745461988195
2306089645405831114107370739922985090810725635160947600829254949567811391
527417408764964324623612928827357473756502731555819746574832578277354817830480916093943535732
166782206349090
5039608483812
22779394003240991729940635387402457235717080073
23174884008941354054844994242306457670422886007267519294811553498520062981088
9379888465970151122427941852081839147561125428377120361098516
4851370931160622254599150919117874463729978188996483031702235879658066666
263962446402901234512400757004778715587484543679574154252814321
386080725531661023940341523726123830253452637178276277203272636730408946001853813544261847
506026518112695319049401500113438880015883164168786587087613685577329244826505995
853765766003041571727941982752375129846256362542268503538675723550767627646485
64915691514101937300896922107778765032041587836421804752327362
9235574571590973726389090392147619820135193089943052820464889147983825
794262758048207670029386770065222950113126
91478800
32687310632916086625372418455638163341778982284204
783034075100973917425178065924838816191619704361135719202582740172462892170122963273533820990331
273617602525557769852631252187557240898061262540420559773149091644393300751865108665599596695445
360949692042264211417548128414147307892643411000394876422352
```

And my result will be:

```
8
44
82
966
88151
96648
91478800
63593696
86212388
139324591
4763506513
3300953792
84617645710
24851084103
5039608483812
166782206349090
69689336023779290
72091970412420810
8602096560157018758
6920677972668613791679
4285137293297191396703
702616993760099773277701
2006589875623412145878326
3443449340302668605052308
2568508222553899614989132
138693350046179064920029198428
2226233916493298335782492406184
3746855980099062683149629582771
4381858583387279277494367930538
89010681446075323502110552896366
617218738782517673738696836650709347
6766894084508701303181966954454442649
48048060500795311454501362396164002281
982252143663373494231929681150950636211
794262758048207670029386770065222950113126
871937317295006166948610659392371453127620
4900146572543628830293235422623540449026979
56055923387811165695520181970960556995748385
41417855736231689319726325108873908732322628
57500297590012603652986133599394871645776460
6075082871705572350813503266092842439231032244
22779394003240991729940635387402457235717080073
97717671655657189481516207050719062493363178584
29961611875126871444847810377719588732057005401
59064571843258418539809783946176028799168327197
3499362168023660581620889357853145012397063659728
32687310632916086625372418455638163341778982284204
44466191365953341779604153931359991009249825932467038
360949692042264211417548128414147307892643411000394876422352
799898013447209990576845913871859165418584121624031762316631
103760370650030890704420196453564751405138564548779976442730
9379888465970151122427941852081839147561125428377120361098516
7140136715304755447794330632416535814668937888353462780963074
79889616038675409793789137873748992624206633449485792697950955
64915691514101937300896922107778765032041587836421804752327362
189464003228859631246844678939878442100631407094488634370181145
263962446402901234512400757004778715587484543679574154252814321
6853035336068603185837379598609710965901821183057340152937719965
13350830253644406272592098943542479448539695237424116030768219886
96144167763113033526215836335259504732455722379148990370590444393
9235574571590973726389090392147619820135193089943052820464889147983825
3123578614526005010789440062175923385894745490067711730621296066747362
7352625455571982316988892359385804345281600126036030867648944342681034
6730285737803282364443175816103191082917262371727029128242169800609774
595511428927857027243741014585070698077724714702592038259539625900191041
4851370931160622254599150919117874463729978188996483031702235879658066666
2306089645405831114107370739922985090810725635160947600829254949567811391
82226197486758707862569829863301345843404256425288167712035595632448134024
497010206818067722087306230802257700034825862515267073569769100385728461314
841914798700287274894330827423742367016300562418119497681768534733683171159
8029462867402623010267220669038328276828159277704969882249658925340931197482
23174884008941354054844994242306457670422886007267519294811553498520062981088
721655363593196254631465218524410129464006729720524491959093939538800477879025
853765766003041571727941982752375129846256362542268503538675723550767627646485
407248179926838952899179921191873979655396776466610725637337844938107386865231
347055068146981261045909920471491104435367358281493074132530787003286631891260
357047822507894621064882425810251495984339153706718863150434921883251916931938
4879666158760447227244804904490661525075569972625784785166402241961211585507098
506026518112695319049401500113438880015883164168786587087613685577329244826505995
689652207582048074063885557314598131439882640463089732166634627009727882839802329
4827062832427344897934914852861881127816196306013748993413309020967615943118038713
887419023647277091177508895423672748680390346760451960405476096892458561446000021772
6459413133895599543512093010172681584992295387756374602296715030084689407214761953434
6046724675206781253805417697364063874537349942332939012160502967377173420319837265456476
386080725531661023940341523726123830253452637178276277203272636730408946001853813544261847
424250809729923008382471798976997991102352666012166168135388490453419791993437348248692902
226308783007518652278892711651945969504116481446022861103004230456764884348840645054713740
399461832935777584631551322242458863336488933972064475755775387970693429489605542902103453
3027671510958920867119822769967026975150513671872284364883316076664947814983178816236371615
75655297913491802872733439380949625942090642103288135379733240968108838187718699296561107131
527417408764964324623612928827357473756502731555819746574832578277354817830480916093943535732
3266084681485344181145502865406724087976265728762903576706273055985600897547821990716776855603
5346081954679885708665439539884162946087234174562850518034347368864646546761391881199484426332
663851293951736587506669665707856376236045468061542850096311090080985050730443008535949871380862
783034075100973917425178065924838816191619704361135719202582740172462892170122963273533820990331
273617602525557769852631252187557240898061262540420559773149091644393300751865108665599596695445
4513813970506423806366556964549587926118285563093984149180914445198582562248005532967426935363394
98727463407922846430489331897187874972506399980149269216341792683934266326553372651336825100910502
195294541694873319042720380485249001380825565396311663127260228626400961443707964165554187168383846
2531882366050391355575974134566968043538613212060996149075948904530719392416580359757169745461988195
```

where these four strings are not sorted in place:

```
22779394003240991729940635387402457235717080073
97717671655657189481516207050719062493363178584
29961611875126871444847810377719588732057005401
59064571843258418539809783946176028799168327197
```

I'm sure `quickSort` is correct and safe, because if I rewrite my `isAsc` function to:

```
private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length()) {
        return true;
    } else if (a.length() == b.length()) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) >= 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

my program will pass the test case. In my view I didn't see there's anything wrong with my first approach, but why it failed to sort some of the strings?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare two string, character by character, the logic should be:

1. If ch1 < ch2 then return true (it's definitely ascending)
2. If ch1 > ch2 then return false (it's definitely descending)
3. Otherwise compare next character

But that is not what your code is doing.

First, let's simplify your code, so it's easier to see what it's doing. Let's stop using `else` after a `return`, and flip the second test so we can just `return`.

```
private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return true;
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return false;
    boolean yep = true;
    for (int i =0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
        if (a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            yep = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return yep;
}
```

Second, setting `yep` to false and breaking the loop is the same as simply returning false. Again, lets flip the test.

```
private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return true;
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return false;
    boolean yep = true;
    for (int i =0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
        if (a.charAt(i) >= b.charAt(i))
            return false;
        continue;
    }
    return yep;
}
```

Now the `continue` is redundant, and `yep` is always true.

```
private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return true;
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return false;
    for (int i =0; i < a.length(); ++i)
        if (a.charAt(i) >= b.charAt(i))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Finally, we can easily see the problem of `if (a.charAt(i) >= b.charAt(i)) return false;`, so lets fix it.

```
private static boolean isAsc(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return true;
    if (a.length() > b.length())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); ++i) {
        if (a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i))
            return true;
        if (a.charAt(i) > b.charAt(i))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course, to be consistent with your other version, that uses `compareTo()`, you should change that last statement to `return false`, so both return false when strings are equal. Doesn't really matter to result, but still ...

Comment: I understand your general logic, but this revised code will cause an overflow  error when executing the recursion of  `quickSort(arr, i, high);`. Not sure what caused this.